# Me salen símbolos en vez de números en el txt que creo en Java cuando escribo los datos en la consola

Tags: java, archivo

Este es el código:

```
System.out.println("Nombre: ");
                String nombre = Teclado.cadena();
                System.out.println("Capital: ");
                String capital = Teclado.cadena();
                System.out.println("Superficie: ");
                int superficie = Teclado.entero();
                System.out.println("Habitantes: ");
                int habitantes = Teclado.entero();
                System.out.println("¿Tiene costa (true) o no (false)?: ");
                boolean costero = Teclado.booleano();
                String costeroTexto = (costero == true) ? "sí tiene costa" : "no tiene costa";

                File fichero = new File("miPais.txt");

                try
                {
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fichero, true);
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                    bw.write(nombre);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(capital);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(superficie);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(habitantes);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(costeroTexto);

                    bw.close();
                    fw.close();

                    System.out.println("Archivo creado correctamente");
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Bueno, pues cuando escribo los datos de superficie y habitantes el archivo txt que quiero crear me sale así:

España
Madrid
뒨

sí tiene costa

Como véis, superficie y habitantes en el archivo txt salen con unos símbolos raros en vez de números ¿Esto por qué y cómo se soluciona?

Comment: ¿Alguien podría responderme, por favor?

Comment: de donde obtienes Teclado?

Comment: de una clase que me he creado yo:

Comment: Intenta convertir los números a string antes de escribirlos

Comment: podrías agregar tu clase Teclado por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente define una codificación al escribir tu archivo, por ejemplo UTF-8, pero en el caso de la clase `FileWriter` no existe un constructor para definir codificación por lo tanto la primera ocasión que creas el archivo puedes realizarlo usando [**BufferedWriter**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#targetText=Class%20BufferedWriter&targetText=Writes%20text%20to%20a%20character,large%20enough%20for%20most%20purposes.).

Ejemplo:

```
   Writer out = null;
        try {
            out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("miPais.txt"), "UTF-8"));
            out.write(aString);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally{
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
        }
```

---

En Java 11 usando la clase [**FileWriter**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html), si puedes definir una codificación de esta forma:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("miPais.txt", Charset.forName("utf-8"), true);
```